# Evaluating Randomness in a shuffled list

Tags: python, random, statistics, analysis

Hi I have multiple pieces of data that contain same values in random orders like this:

```
list1 = [1 5 3 2 4]
list2 = [4 1 5 2 3]
list3 = [2 4 3 5 1]
list4 = [3 2 1 4 5]
list5 = ....
```

They will always have a sequence of numbers like 1-5, or 1-50, etc., but the sequence is shuffled.

1. I am trying to determine if these values are shuffled randomly or not. So far in online searches I only found methods to shuffle the data, but my data is already shuffled. I need to determine if the data is random and to what degree. Does anyone have any ideas for this?
2. I also need to look at which lists might be shuffled in a similar way.

So far, I have looked at how many flips in a sorting algorithm I would have to do to get the right order and used that to evaluate how shuffled the data is. I can also cluster the points to figure out which ones are similar, although that does not answer question 1 about randomness, only question 2. Any other ideas for algorithms or packages that do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems pretty broad and not really specific to Python, or even programming. So, asking this on a more general statistics or math site might help out more.

Comment: Every combination of numbers in your list is equally likely to exist; so in that sense, every list is equally 'random'. However, if you have a different definition of how you want to measure randomness, i.e how different each index is from its ordered state index or something similar, then you can measure randomness from that angle (although one wouldn't really call that random), otherwise, your question is just too broad.

Comment: There are 5! = 120 possible orderings for a list of 5 distinct items. In principle you could do a large number of shuffles and test the hypothesis that the proportion of occurrences is 1/120. This would take a large number of samples, though, and the sampling requirements would grow exponentially for larger lists.